# .TBL database extension

Tags: database

Is there any database out there that uses the .TBL or .tbl file extension?  For example, MySQL uses .frm for some engine types.

I have a file that presumably came out of some database with this file extension.

Unfortunately, most searches lead to useless spam sites or the Unix command troff.

Is there someone out there that has ever worked with a database that stores data in a .TBL file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.computerfileextensions.com/file-extensions.php/TBL ???

Comment: I've seen this one as well.  The ArcView link is the only thing that seems vaguely appropriate.  However, this is not a GIS dataset.